# Unnatural shadows in corners with Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

The problem is that in all my renders the shadows in the corners, where objects/surfaces touch each other, look unnatural. The objects look "floating" above the surface, or "detached", like I cut them from a different picture and photoshopped. It feels like there is no ambient occlusion, if I'm not mistaken. Can you advice how can I improve it?

I use Cycles and Principled BSDF for all materials. The only light source is HDRI. Normals look correct - all faces are blue. The render settings are:

[image]

[image]

Here is the render:

[image]

The shelves look "floating":

[image]

The cabinets and floor also look unnatural:

[image]

Although some objects look not bad. For example, the plant or cabinets and ceiling:

[image]
[image]

Comment: 200 samples with denoising can be really asking for troubles. The less time you spend rendering, the more the denoiser has to invent and approximate what should be there. I might be wrong on this, but that could be the source of your weird shadows. Plus, depending on your HDR, lighting can be weird anyway.

Comment: Render settings look fine, the shadow of the cabinet matches with the one on the plant. I think it looks overall weird because the chosen light setup doesn't valorize the scene. It's an artistic issue, not a technical one. Try to rotate the hdri, or use a different one, find some references that suite your project ant try to match them... ecc

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will try to play with HDR and do more samples.